# Why am I seeing so many for(;;) constructs?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

To my way of thinking, a for loop is used to iterate over a known or determinable range.

```
String[] names = //something;
for ( int i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ) { //do stuff }
```

which is equivalent (scoping of i aside) to :

```
String[] names = //something;
int i = 0;
while (i < names.length )
{
   // do stuff
   i++;
}
```

In other words, the `for` loop is simply a (highly useful) syntactic sugar for a commonly used `while` construct.

However, I'm seeing a lot of `for(;;)` constructs on the web which are functionally equivalent to `while(true)`

What is the reasoning for this?  Why would the infinite for loop be preferred over the infinite while loop?

// I even saw a java textbook that didn't use while loops at all!  Leading to such monstrous constructs as:

```
String input = getInput();
for( ; !inputIsValid(input) ; )
{
   //redo;
}
```

Comment: The main reason is preference. Readability should come into play when making the choice however YMMV.

Comment: Why would anyone prefer the awkward construct?

Comment: I don't prefer the awkward construct so I couldn't answer that. If I don't need a count I'll go _while_, if I do I'll go _for_.

Comment: I suspect it's just what people are used to.  Could also be that for(;;) is less typing than while(true) :)

Comment: language agnostic might be a bad tag, maybe c(ish)-language-agnostic.  A Delphi programmer would never accept such a hideous construct.

Comment: @Luke  If that number of characters makes a difference, you probably shouldn't be allowed near a keyboard :P

Comment: You could swap `while` and `for` here and the question wouldn't change. `while(true)` and `for(;;)` mean the same thing. You obviously have a strong preference for `while`, others may have an equally strong preference for `for`. It's impossible to say that one is more correct than the other.

Comment: If you're going to vote to close, give a reason.

Comment: @chris I just did. Neither is more correct than the other; choosing one is mainly a matter of personal taste. This question should therefore be closed as 'not constructive.'

Comment: Actually, your reasoning is confusing to me.  for(;;) is semantically confusing, AND it is a syntactic rolling up of a common while construct.  for(;;) is a construct that was never intended.  See Edward Robertson's answer for the reason why it was hacked into being.    Furthermore, Why vote to close?  Does the question so offend you?

Comment: @chris, I don't find `for(;;)` confusing at all. It's a standard C idiom, one which you'll documented in section 3.5 of K&R(2e). I understand that *you* don't like it; *you* should understand that others obviously prefer it (else you'd never see it). It may be more or less acceptable in languages other than C; you've tagged this [tag:language-agnostic] which only decreases the possiblity of a definitive answer. *Again,* I voted to close because the Q isn't constructive; if I were offended I would have flagged as offensive instead of or in addition to closing. That is all.

Comment: If the tag is bothering you, then remove it.  Don't close the question.  The QUESTION is language-agnostic. (although, I concede the c-ish comment).  The answer however is not -- in fact it goes to a specific compiler on a specific platform.

Comment: Personally I think there's a real opportunity here to have another syntax entirely for infinite loops: something like `wheeeeeeee { ... }`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's a hold-over from old programming practices on the PDP-11 (yes, I said *old*).  It used to save a single instruction, which was useful for making loops run faster.

See the following for additional information:  http://www.flounder.com/exceptions.htm

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for.  There is a real, legitimate reason, but it is no longer valid.

Comment: @chris Nnnope, modern compilers will sometimes complain about using a constant in the condition of a loop.  It's not purely a holdover.

Comment: There is more to it than that. I can remember writing C in the early 1990's on unix systems and while(true) {} was not an option. There was no standard boolean type, but several unix systems defined their own in C header files. From memory at least one unix vendor defined TRUE as zero supposidly to aid to process function returns as the convention was to return zero on success, and positive numbers were failures. This did mean that while(TRUE) {} was not portable.

Comment: I can't find it right now, but I could swear that a few years ago Dennis Ritchie wrote a post on Usenet stating that this was simply wrong, and he/they use the `for(;;)` syntax as (in their opinion) a more direct statement of intent that there was no criteria being stated for exit from the loop.

Comment: @Ptolemy: Well you could certainly have written `while(1) { }`.

Comment: @Jerry - I don't doubt you, but to me, both forms for infinite loops are dodgy. `while (true)` seems to read as "while true", which in English would usually mean "while <implicit condition from context> is true". But with `for` you have a *while* condition just as with `while`. It doesn't state when to exit the loop except by reverse logic - as with `while`, it states when the loop body runs. Therefore, leaving the condition empty reads to me like the loop body will never run. Of course, interpreted that way, it would be a useless loop construct, but IMO it's still how it reads.

Comment: @Steve314: I agree with your conclusion, but for a different reason: most infinite loops are not really meant to be infinite at all, and I don't like having a loop that says it runs infinitely when that's not the intent. In *many* cases, it's pretty easy to restructure the loop to express the real exit condition where it belongs instead of in an `if`/`break` somewhere inside the loop.

Answer (score 10):

some compilers will give a warning (something like *conditional expression is constant*) when using `while( 1 )` but with `for( ; ; )` there's nothing to warn about. Programmers want code without warnings, so they use the for variant.

Comment: Some things compilers warn about are perfectly valid, though, and even (in some special cases) unavoidable. So some of us treat warnings as, well, warnings. If you ignore them, of course you can get swamped in the damned things and not see the important ones - but there's pragmas and options to disable warnings, locally or globally. Basically, yes it's better to not have warnings, but I usually need a stronger reason than that to adopt a worse code style. Here it's not worse just different, but "infinite" loops are rare (or else very bad style) anyway.

Answer (score 5):

It's a habit acquired from C programming where there isn't a boolean type. While(1) would be the equivalent potentially but For(;;) is often used as it shows up in K&R if I remember correctly. I suspect that there was a hardware reason in there somewhere as well.

Comment: ...suspect there _was_ a hardware reason...

Comment: As Edward Robertson mentioned, the reason is because the C compiler on the PDP-11 didn't realize that the true in "while(true)" was a compile time constant and would add an extra instruction (a compare) when generating assembly. Because of the limited resources available on the PDP-11, programmers used the for loop to optimize that one extra instruction out of the program.

Answer (score 3):

for(;;) can be read as "forever" which some find more natural than "while true".

Comment: While this isn't the original reason, it is a secondary reason why the preference stuck long after the original reason became obsolete.  It's very hard to trot out any evidence to support this, though, other than to ask long-experienced programmers.

Answer (score -2):

All the experienced programmers I have asked can recognize `for(;;)` more quickly than `while(true)` or `while(1)`.

Comment: Any programmer that's worth a damn should be able to recognize all three instantly.  All three are common enough that anyone who's spent more than 5 minutes reading code has seen each of them a bunch of times.

Comment: Studies have shown that experienced programmers can comprehend `for(;;)` 14ms faster than `while(1)` :-)